# Read array as parameter in Web Service method

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I am having a web service

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute()]
        [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://localhost:1185/getPOData", RequestNamespace = "http://localhost:1185/", ResponseNamespace = "http://localhost:1185/", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
        public string getPOData([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Namespace = "")] [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("IDOC", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)] ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOC[] ORDERS05_VEN)
        {



        }



[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1015")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public  class ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOC {

    private ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCEDI_DC40[] eDI_DC40Field;

    private ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK01[] e1EDK01Field;

    private ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK14[] e1EDK14Field;

    private ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK03[] e1EDK03Field;

    private ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK04[] e1EDK04Field;

    private ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK05[] e1EDK05Field;

    private ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDKA1[] e1EDKA1Field;

    private string bEGINField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("EDI_DC40", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCEDI_DC40[] EDI_DC40 {
        get {
            return this.eDI_DC40Field;
        }
        set {
            this.eDI_DC40Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDK01", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK01[] E1EDK01 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDK01Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDK01Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDK14", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK14[] E1EDK14 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDK14Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDK14Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDK03", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK03[] E1EDK03 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDK03Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDK03Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDK04", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK04[] E1EDK04 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDK04Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDK04Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDK05", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK05[] E1EDK05 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDK05Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDK05Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDKA1", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDKA1[] E1EDKA1 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDKA1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDKA1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDK02", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK02[] E1EDK02 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDK02Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDK02Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDK17", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK17[] E1EDK17 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDK17Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDK17Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDK18", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK18[] E1EDK18 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDK18Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDK18Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDK35", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK35[] E1EDK35 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDK35Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDK35Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDK36", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK36[] E1EDK36 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDK36Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDK36Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDKT1", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDKT1[] E1EDKT1 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDKT1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDKT1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDP01", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDP01[] E1EDP01 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDP01Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDP01Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1CUCFG", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1CUCFG[] E1CUCFG {
        get {
            return this.e1CUCFGField;
        }
        set {
            this.e1CUCFGField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDL37", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDL37[] E1EDL37 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDL37Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDL37Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("E1EDS01", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDS01[] E1EDS01 {
        get {
            return this.e1EDS01Field;
        }
        set {
            this.e1EDS01Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string BEGIN {
        get {
            return this.bEGINField;
        }
        set {
            this.bEGINField = value;
        }
    }
}



/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1015")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public  class ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCEDI_DC40 {

    private string tABNAMField;

    private string mANDTField;

    private string dOCNUMField;


    private string mESCODField;

    private string mESFCTField;

    private string sTDField;

    private string sTDVRSField;

    private string sTDMESField;

    private string sNDPORField;

    private string sNDPRTField;

    private string sNDPFCField;

    private string sNDPRNField;

    private string sNDSADField;

    private string sNDLADField;

    private string cREDATField;

    private string cRETIMField;

    private string rEFINTField;

    private string rEFGRPField;
    private string sEGMENTField;


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string TABNAM {
        get {
            return this.tABNAMField;
        }
        set {
            this.tABNAMField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string MANDT {
        get {
            return this.mANDTField;
        }
        set {
            this.mANDTField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string DOCNUM {
        get {
            return this.dOCNUMField;
        }
        set {
            this.dOCNUMField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string DOCREL {
        get {
            return this.dOCRELField;
        }
        set {
            this.dOCRELField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string STATUS {
        get {
            return this.sTATUSField;
        }
        set {
            this.sTATUSField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string DIRECT {
        get {
            return this.dIRECTField;
        }
        set {
            this.dIRECTField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string OUTMOD {
        get {
            return this.oUTMODField;
        }
        set {
            this.oUTMODField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string EXPRSS {
        get {
            return this.eXPRSSField;
        }
        set {
            this.eXPRSSField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string TEST {
        get {
            return this.tESTField;
        }
        set {
            this.tESTField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string IDOCTYP {
        get {
            return this.iDOCTYPField;
        }
        set {
            this.iDOCTYPField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string CIMTYP {
        get {
            return this.cIMTYPField;
        }
        set {
            this.cIMTYPField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string MESTYP {
        get {
            return this.mESTYPField;
        }
        set {
            this.mESTYPField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string MESCOD {
        get {
            return this.mESCODField;
        }
        set {
            this.mESCODField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string MESFCT {
        get {
            return this.mESFCTField;
        }
        set {
            this.mESFCTField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string STD {
        get {
            return this.sTDField;
        }
        set {
            this.sTDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string STDVRS {
        get {
            return this.sTDVRSField;
        }
        set {
            this.sTDVRSField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string STDMES {
        get {
            return this.sTDMESField;
        }
        set {
            this.sTDMESField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string SNDPOR {
        get {
            return this.sNDPORField;
        }
        set {
            this.sNDPORField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string SNDPRT {
        get {
            return this.sNDPRTField;
        }
        set {
            this.sNDPRTField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string SNDPFC {
        get {
            return this.sNDPFCField;
        }
        set {
            this.sNDPFCField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string SNDPRN {
        get {
            return this.sNDPRNField;
        }
        set {
            this.sNDPRNField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string SNDSAD {
        get {
            return this.sNDSADField;
        }
        set {
            this.sNDSADField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string SNDLAD {
        get {
            return this.sNDLADField;
        }
        set {
            this.sNDLADField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string RCVPOR {
        get {
            return this.rCVPORField;
        }
        set {
            this.rCVPORField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string RCVPRT {
        get {
            return this.rCVPRTField;
        }
        set {
            this.rCVPRTField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string RCVPFC {
        get {
            return this.rCVPFCField;
        }
        set {
            this.rCVPFCField = value;
        }
    }




    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1015")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
    public  class ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK01 {

        private string aCTIONField;

        private string kZABSField;

        private string cURCYField;

        private string hWAERField;

        private string wKURSField;


    private string zTERMField;

    private string kUNDEUINRField;

    private string eIGENUINRField;

    private string bSARTField;

    private string bELNRField;

    private string nTGEWField;

    private string bRGEWField;

    private string gEWEIField;

    private string fKART_RLField;

    private string aBLADField;

    private string bSTZDField;

    private string vSARTField;

    private string vSART_BEZField;

    private string rECIPNT_NOField;

    private string kZAZUField;

    private string aUTLFField;

    private string aUGRUField;

    private string aUGRU_BEZField;

    private string aBRVWField;

    private string aBRVW_BEZField;

    private string fKTYPField;

    private string lIFSKField;

    private string lIFSK_BEZField;

    private string eMPSTField;

    private string aBTNRField;

    private string dELCOField;

    private string wKURS_MField;

    private ArrayOfORDERS05_VENIDOCIDOCE1EDK01ZE1EDK01_VEN[] zE1EDK01_VENField;

    private string sEGMENTField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string ACTION {
        get {
            return this.aCTIONField;
        }
        set {
            this.aCTIONField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string KZABS {
        get {
            return this.kZABSField;
        }
        set {
            this.kZABSField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string CURCY {
        get {
            return this.cURCYField;
        }
        set {
            this.cURCYField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string HWAER {
        get {
            return this.hWAERField;
        }
        set {
            this.hWAERField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string WKURS {
        get {
            return this.wKURSField;
        }
        set {
            this.wKURSField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string ZTERM {
        get {
            return this.zTERMField;
        }
        set {
            this.zTERMField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string KUNDEUINR {
        get {
            return this.kUNDEUINRField;
        }
        set {
            this.kUNDEUINRField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string EIGENUINR {
        get {
            return this.eIGENUINRField;
        }
        set {
            this.eIGENUINRField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string BSART {
        get {
            return this.bSARTField;
        }
        set {
            this.bSARTField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string BELNR {
        get {
            return this.bELNRField;
        }
        set {
            this.bELNRField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string NTGEW {
        get {
            return this.nTGEWField;
        }
        set {
            this.nTGEWField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string BRGEW {
        get {
            return this.bRGEWField;
        }
        set {
            this.bRGEWField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string GEWEI {
        get {
            return this.gEWEIField;
        }
        set {
            this.gEWEIField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string FKART_RL {
        get {
            return this.fKART_RLField;
        }
        set {
            this.fKART_RLField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string ABLAD {
        get {
            return this.aBLADField;
        }
        set {
            this.aBLADField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string BSTZD {
        get {
            return this.bSTZDField;
        }
        set {
            this.bSTZDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string VSART {
        get {
            return this.vSARTField;
        }
        set {
            this.vSARTField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string VSART_BEZ {
        get {
            return this.vSART_BEZField;
        }
        set {
            this.vSART_BEZField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string RECIPNT_NO {
        get {
            return this.rECIPNT_NOField;
        }
        set {
            this.rECIPNT_NOField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string KZAZU {
        get {
            return this.kZAZUField;
        }
        set {
            this.kZAZUField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string AUTLF {
        get {
            return this.aUTLFField;
        }
        set {
            this.aUTLFField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string AUGRU {
        get {
            return this.aUGRUField;
        }
        set {
            this.aUGRUField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string AUGRU_BEZ {
        get {
            return this.aUGRU_BEZField;
        }
        set {
            this.aUGRU_BEZField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string ABRVW {
        get {
            return this.aBRVWField;
        }
        set {
            this.aBRVWField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string ABRVW_BEZ {
        get {
            return this.aBRVW_BEZField;
        }
        set {
            this.aBRVW_BEZField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string FKTYP {
        get {
            return this.fKTYPField;
        }
        set {
            this.fKTYPField = value;
        }
    }
```

Now I want to know how I will read this in my web method, getPOData, as the parameter is array of array of class which is XMLArray Attr. How would I read the parameter and create the xml file from web service.

Comment: How about posting here ALL the code you have...?

Comment: Hi JoriO, I am not able to post the websrvice as it contains too much code and here it is having restriction on posting code.

Comment: Ok, you didn't get my sarcasm. What I meant to say was that you could spend some time and try to isolate your problem so that you can post much less code here.

Comment: I have uploaded the web service code here, http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2014/10_w41/876087/Service.asmx.cs and the sample xml http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2014/10_w41/876091/PO-ORDERS.txt

Comment: You should try [Servicestack.net](https://servicestack.net). Go to Downloads and scroll to the bottom for the trial / older free versions, which are still good. Though if you have a commercial project, you might go with theirs. It will save you tons of time trying to figure out how to send arrays, etc.

Comment: Is there any other way out :(